# XAML Split Page selected element tag highlight

Tags: visual-studio, ide

In Visual Studio looking at a XAML file in split page mode (design one half XAML the other)

I have a `<Grid>` and I select it in the Design half, the XAML half gets a light grey shading on the element tag.

I can see the highlight fine on my PC but not on my laptop as the LCD screen is bright.

Can I change the highlight in a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the inactive selected text color here:

- Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
- Show settings for: Text Editor
- Display Items: Inactive Selected Text
- Item Background: Custom ...

Comment: Thanks Rick, Worked like a charm :-)

Comment: I searche for this forever in Fonts and Colors. Thanks for the tip.